# how to send mail , using outlook - right to left text in the message?

Tags: c#, winforms

i send mail like this:

```
 string sampleDisplayName = "Me";
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application sampleApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem sampleMessage = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)sampleApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                    sampleMessage.To = "Me@Gmail.com"; 
                    sampleMessage.Subject = "My subject"; 
                    LosMSG  = "My message here";
                    LosMSG += "\n------------";
                    LosMSG += "\nand here";
                    sampleMessage.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText;
                    sampleMessage.Body = LosMSG;
                    sampleMessage.BCC = ToHoSend; 
                    int samplePosition = (int)sampleMessage.Body.Length + 1;
                    int sampleType = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
                    sampleMessage.Display(true); 
                    sampleMessage = null;
                    sampleApp = null;
```

but the message is left-to-right

how i do it right-to-left ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Outlook automation object model doesn't include support for RTL: if you make your message format HTML, though, you can include [the CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_direction.asp) `direction:rtl;`

Comment: thank's for the help, but where to include the CSS or where to plan ?

Comment: Create your HTML including the style info (best to use inline styles for HTML mail) and assign it to the MailItem's HTMLBody property.